# For each is printing same Item

Tags: vb.net, foreach

The variable ListofBloodType is returning the correct values not sure why in the loop I am getting the first value 4 times ( the count 4 is correct also but printing the first value 4 times is not)

```
Dim tempTreatmentForBloodType As List(Of BloodType) = New List(Of BloodType)()
Dim ListofBloodType = getPatientBloodType(i.PatientID)

For Each i As PatientBloodType In ListofBloodType
   tempTreatmentForBloodType.Add(([Enum].Parse(GetType(BloodType), getReference().Description)))

Next
```

Comment: Because you're not using the loop variable `PatientBloodType`?

Comment: not enough info here to be able to give an answer. We don't know what `getPatientBloodType()` does, we don't know the value of `i` or `PatientID`, and we don't know what `getReference()` does. Although you loop though `ListOfBloodType` (assuming it's populated correctly as you state) you don't appear to actually use any value from it, instead you do something with `getReference` which as I've pointed out, we know nothing about.

Comment: GSerg, You are right, I am not using i.. I should add i.PatientID in the gerReference part! Many Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was exactly what GSerg pointed at, I was not using the loop variable. I created new getReference method with parameter to get the data for a particular patient. Here is the code that worked for me! I hope it helps new VB programmers like me!

```
Dim tempTreatmentForBloodType As List(Of BloodType) = New List(Of BloodType)()
Dim ListofBloodType = getPatientBloodType(i.PatientID)

For Each i As PatientBloodType In ListofBloodType
 tempTreatmentForBloodType.Add(([Enum].Parse(GetType(BloodType), 
 getReference(i.PatientID).Description)))

Next
```

Many Thanks to the above helpful comments!

Comment: Code Review: You should rename "i", it's not an index when doing a For Each. I also find it strange that you use "i" before the loop.